# Mocking Observable with Jest - rxjs

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rxjs, jestjs

I have a simple Observable piping from another Observable that I want to test.

```
const loginState$ = messageBusObservables.loginState$.pipe(
    startWith({ isLoggedIn: false })
    pluck('isLoggedIn'),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
```

messageBusObservables is an object of observables. Where loginState$ is an Observable.

In my tests, I thought I would easily be able to mock the './messageBus' module like this: (how the module is imported is irrelevant, but import preferred)

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import './messageBus'
jest.mock('./messageBus', () => ({
  loginState$: of({ isLoggedIn: true }),
}))
```

However, Jest throws the error:

> babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
>       Invalid variable access: of

I have tried, putting it in a `jest.fn()` I have tried extracting `of({ isLoggedIn: true })` to a variable. But I keep getting the same error from jest.

So how can I mock the input into my Observables using Jest? I'll run into the same problem with other observables using .merge, .zip etc.

It needs to be a real observable that is the input of my other observables. I just want to mock the value with something like `of()` rather than mocking an object, with a method on it, that returns an object with a .pipe method etc. (I don't want to mock the functionality of an Observable). I want to pass it a real observable with a value set in my unit test.

I also need these mocks to be dynamic. So the mock from 1 assertion can be different from the mock in the next assertion. (clearing them with something like a beforeEach)

**EDIT:**

I also tried to use babel-plugin-rewire to mock this module, this worked fine in the *.test.js file where I was mocking it. But in the actual file no matter what I set the export to using rewire, it always got imported as the original Observable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the reason you are getting this message:

> babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: of

is because jest automatically hoists calls to jest.mock so that they happen before the imports.

You have two options to get around this default behaviour, the simple way is to use jest.doMock which is NOT hoisted:

```
jest.doMock('./messageBus', () => ({
  loginState$: of({ isLoggedIn: true }),
}))
```

Alternatively, you can prefix all the variables referenced inside the mock factory passed to jest.mock with "mock":

```
const mockMessageBus = {
  loginState$: of({ isLoggedIn: true }),
}
jest.doMock('./messageBus', () => mockMessageBus)
```

(note that you are responsible for ensuring all mock variables referenced in the factory function are in scope when jest.mock is called)

Comment: Thank you Jesse! doMock is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You're close.

You are trying to mock the module by [passing a module factory as the second parameter to `jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options).  The main constraint of that approach is that the module factory must be completely self-contained and "is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables".

Referencing `of` from `rxjs` in the module factory (as you have found) breaks that constraint and causes the error you are seeing.

Fortunately there are other ways to mock modules.

From what I can see of your code it looks like the easiest approach would be to create a [Manual Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) of the `messageBus` module.

---

Create a `__mocks__` folder in the same directory as `messageBus.js` and create the mock (also called `messageBus.js`) within the `__mocks__` folder.

`__mocks__/messageBus.js` will look something like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'

export default {
  loginState$: of({ isLoggedIn: true })
}
```

Then [tell Jest you want to use the manual mock within your test](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) by calling

`jest.mock('messageBus');`

at the top of your test file.

[That call is hoisted by Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) and ensures that any code that imports `messageBus` during the test will get the mocked module.

Comment: Thanks Brian :) This would work if I just needed it to be one static mock. But not ideal with dynamic mocks that needs to change between different assertions.

Thank you for the answer though, much appreciated!

Comment: @MLyck Did you end up using `require`?  Your sample uses `import` which would require the hoisting behavior of `jest.mock` since `jest.doMock` would happen too late.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using require (unfortunately have to do the whole .default part). With Jesse's suggestion of using doMock. By requiring the module just after the mock to avoid the hoisting problem.

Then in jest's beforeEach, I am clearing the moduleRegistry so it gets reset and that gives me the dynamic mocks with Observables.

Comment: @MLyck gotcha, I didn't know you were using `require`.  I recommend you edit your question to state that since the accepted answer won't work if people are using ES6 `import`

Comment: the question is about a way to make it work. How it's accomplished (as long as it's not a super nasty hack is less important than getting it to actually work), obviously if there's a way to do it with an ES6 import that would be preferred and probably be the better answer.

I will edit it to say that I needed the mocks to be dynamic and say how the module is imported is irellevant.